# Creating a new or extending an existing SplitContainer

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, controls

Actually, I think I would prefer to simply extend the existing SplitContainer control for winforms.

What I would love is to add my own SplitContainer from the toolbox, and then add as many more panels to it as needed. And remove as needed.

Something like this:

[image: Picture of SplitContainer that lets you add a new panel]

How would one begin extending the SplitContainer?

Comment: When you finish creating that control, you probably have somethging that allow you to nest another split panel insided a panel, that is exactly what you already have :)

Comment: I need this support during Design-Time, I can't just keep adding SplitContainer inside of another, it becomes far-less manageable. If that's what you meant. But thanks for the suggestion. :)

Comment: A literal answer to "how would one begin extending the SplitContainer" would be `class MySplitContainer : SplitContainer`. However, I agree with Felice. Just nest the containers. It is a lot more manageable than you might think.

Comment: Hmm. I'll try nesting - and I'll also try extending lol. Thanks for your advice, will keep it in mind for when I give up on trying to extend it. :)

Comment: You won't get it done by inheriting from SplitContainer, too many private methods that you can't override.  Give it a week before you give up and start nesting splitters or switch to DockPanel Suite.

Comment: Thanks, Hans. I just downloaded DockPanel S, will give it a go. Is it really that hard to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

why don't you just use Panelcontrols with Dockstyle and Splittercontrols?

if you realy want to write your own Splittcontainer you have to write the Control itself, the ParentControlDesigner and a DesignerActionList.

Answer (score 0):

Is it legal to answer old question?

What I'm suggesting is using TableLayoutPanel since it can be added more column and rows as per needed. And you can add panel and set properties of the item inside the layout to dock fill.

[Edit column with percent, autosize based from content size or absolute fixed pixel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KzNCa.png)

[Click on tiny arrow on TableLayoutPanel to open the layout configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/comon.png)

[Normal windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QcnYz.png)

[Maximized windows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YofEA.png)